# Add Self Signed Certificate without promting Yes/No from User

Tags: java, ssl, import, keystore, keytool

Using some batch file, I want to add the untrusted self signed certificate within Java Keystore.

**Command is**

```
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias server-alias
-file server.cer -keystore cacerts.jks -keypass changeit -storepass changeit
```

After running above command, the screen promts for Trust of certificate using Y/N.

```
Trust this certificate? [no]:
```

But I don't want to provide Y/N here.

Is there a way to complete the import using a single command or some additional import switch if any?

Comment: ^^ Personally, I would consider a succinct answer on here preferable to wading through documentation. Perhaps the original questioner read the docs and missed it..

Answer (score 243, accepted):

The option `-noprompt` doesn't prompt the input Y/N from a user and assumes `yes`.

More details can found by running command `keytool -importcert -help` on terminal.

Comment: well correct, but the help is not very informative, it tells only "-noprompt:  do not prompt" not telling what to prompt for. If the password is omitted it should fail, not prompt for password.

Answer (score 0):

As such, keytool is most likely looking for "yes" in your locale ("si" in this case).